# How to insert data to SQLServer with GORM by using *DB.Create()

Tags: sql-server, go, insert, go-gorm

I find two ways to insert data into SQLServer with GORM.

1. `GORM.DB.Exec("insert into [tableA] (value1,value2) VALUES (?,?)",v1,v2)`. It works.
2. `GROM.DB.Create(&myDataStruct).Error`. This reports Error and message is "LastInsertId is not supported. Please use the OUTPUT clause or add `select ID = convert(bigint, SCOPE_IDENTITY())` to the end of your query."

I understand what's the means of this instruction, but I don't know how to code.
Thanks for any help.

following my code

```
db := mssql.GetMssqlDB()
    defer db.Close()

    newData := mssql.People{
        Name: "Tom",
        Age:  12,
    }
    err := db.Create(&newData).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println()
    }
```

and data struct

```
type People struct {
    ID   int64  `gorm:"primary_key;column:id"`
    Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
    Age  int    `gorm:"column:age"`
}

func (p People) TableName() string {
    return "dbo.people"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and have been fixed since https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/pull/2690.
If you get the same error, try update your gorm and it should work.